# PDF type recognition programmatically

Tags: pdf

I need to recognize if a PDF file is a dynamic form or a read only PDF in my code. No matter which programing language.
Is there any way to be able to detect if my target PDF is a form or not?

Comment: A form can be read-only, too, e.g. if all fields are read only... Thus, do you merely want to recognise forms or do you actually want to check for editable fields?

Comment: My goal is recognize if the PDF is read only and has no editable fields. So in my code I will have different actions like, disable printing if PDF has no intractive properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the presence of an "AcroForm" dictionary in the document "Catalog" dictionary. The AcroForm dictionary will be present if the PDF has any kind of form field, signature field, or XFA fields. You'll still need some sort of PDF library tool to parse the PDF objects but there's one available in most languages at this point.

That said, several PDF viewers and online services do allow users to just type onto static PDF files that don't have interactive form fields. I'm not sure if you want to control for that case though.

Comment: I am using AcroPDF 7.0 with vb6 OCX and have some properties and methods but not any thing that help to get this property.

Comment: You'll need a library; something that will let you parse the PDF and get information about the objects.